# How to connect and call a function with a different account using hardhat-deploy?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am using "hardhat-deploy" npm package to deploy the smart contracts.

Inside the deploy script, I am trying to call a function like so:

```
**await trueYield.connect(player).stakeEther(30, data)**
```

The contract deploys fine but then it gives error:

```
TypeError: staking.connect is not a function
```

How can I connect to a different account than "deployer" and call a function on the contract?

Comment: contract.connect(player) is the correct way, but the error msg looks like is not raised by the code you showed, could you show more code detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this line of code after your contract is deployed:

```js
const contract = await ethers.getContract("ContractName")
```

now when you use `contract.connect()` it should work